# Are there apple macs with ivy bridge CPU already on sale?

Tags: mac, ivy-bridge

If not, then when? I tried to google it out but couldn't find any dates. I am especially interested about macbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Mac with Intel HD 4000 graphics would be [Ivy Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Bridge_%28microarchitecture%29). As it stands, all [notebooks](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/compare/notebooks) have HD 4000 graphics.